# Single Wordpress Installation with Sub domains

Tags: subdomains, wordpress-version

I have installed buddypress within a wordpress blog.
now my client wants to use domain like "forums.ourdomain.com"  & "groups.ourdomains.com"
to point buddpress forums that are installed within my wordpress blog.

is that possible? actually my client dont want to install a new copy of wordpress for these sub domains and want to handle everything through single installation.

any one guide me is that possible if yes then how?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to have WordPress use subdomains is:

- Install separate instances of WP on each subdomain
- Install a [Multsite WP instance with subdomains](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Types_of_multisite_network)

So: Sorry, but no.

Comment: pointing out subdomain to a page within wordpress is not possible right?

Comment: Not in any way I can think of.